# Two XYZ layers with same projection but different grids. TileGrid extent ignored?

Tags: openlayers

I have two XYZ sources with a custom projection (EPSG:3059) and I want to display both layers at the same time, plus an OSM layer. The difficulty is that resolution of my sources differs by factor of 5 (and extents of the tile at z=0 are different consequently), so I can't use the same TileGrid for both.

I assumed that Projection object is responsible only for transformations between meters and source coordinates (and vise versa), while TileGrid object is responsible for requesting correct X Y Z. So I assumed that I need to create one Projection for both sources, and two different TileGrids.
However, it seems that extent of TileGrid is completely ignored and extent of the Projection is what defines which tiles will be loaded.

I calculated manually extents of the tile x=0 y=0 z=0 for both my custom sources:

```
const extent2k = [-5120900, -13757822.445178203, 12635022.445178203, 3998100];
const extent10k = [-5120900, -13757822.445178203, 12635022.445178203, 3998100];
```

If I create a projection without extent specified:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3059","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-6000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
register(proj4);
const projection = getProjection('EPSG:3059');
```

and create two TileGrids with different extents:

```
const tileGrid10k = new TileGrid({
    extent: extent10k,
    resolutions: resolutions10k,
});
const tileGrid2k = new TileGrid({
    extent: extent2k,
    resolutions: resolutions2k,
});
```

and then add three layers - two mine with this projection & TileGrids, plus OSM one - to the map, only OSM layer works properly. Both my custom layers request wrong tiles.

If I set extent of the projection to `projection.setExtent(extent10k);`, OSM and the first my custom layer work, but the second doesn't. If I set projection extent to `projection.setExtent(extent2k);`, OSM and the second layer work, but the first layer doesn't.

Looks like extent of the TileGrid itself doesn't change how XYZ are calculated, and only extent of the projection matters. Is it supposed to be this way?

I tried to create two different projections this way:

```
const projection10k = getProjection('EPSG:3059');
projection10k.setExtent(extent10k);

const projection2k = getProjection('EPSG:3059');
projection2k.setExtent(extent2k);
```

but without success - getProjection returns the same instance so I can't have two different extents.

What approach would be a correct one to solve my task of having two XYZ layers with different tile 0/0/0 extent but the same projection?

Answer (score 0):

Ooops.
The reason of this behavior was me passing the TileGrids to wrong objects - instead of passing it to XYZ() options I was passing them to TileLayer() when TileLayer doesn't take tileGrid as an option at all.

XYZ initializer has a fallback:

```
var tileGrid = options.tileGrid !== undefined
    ? options.tileGrid
    : createXYZ({
        extent: extentFromProjection(projection), ...
```

so it uses projection's extent indeed.

Now I have projection created without specifying en extent, and two TileGrids with different extents passed to XYZ() sources. All three layers work as supposed.